# is there failover's logs in google cloud sql?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I had a failover on my PostgreSQL instance on gcp, i have logs and metrics about the instance and metrics all looks good, but i don't have a log with the reason for the failover (something as well as a network failure or zone), Is there any way to know the reason for the failover?

Answer (score 0):

This is info is only available if you have support service (only with pay), this steps are:
1.- paid 4 support
2.- open a ticker for ask to info